# Why does the chlorination of indene occur with syn selectivity in heptane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereoselectivity, c-c-addition

In the chlorination of indene to form 1,2-dichloro-2,3-dihydro-1​*H*-indene in heptane as solvent, the *syn* dichloride is formed as the major product, as reported in [*J. Org. Chem.* **1980,** *45* (25), 5150–5155](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo01313a025)):

[image: Reaction scheme]

The explanation I was given for this was that "in a non-polar solvent, the ion pair collapses quickly". What does this mean, and why is the stereoselectivity reversed, as compared to typical halogenations which proceed via a halonium ion intermediate to give *anti* dihalides?

Answer (score 11):

**Key**

The reaction is run in heptane, a non-polar solvent.  **A non-polar solvent will not stabilize or support ions as well as a polar solvent**.

**Background**

When the $\ce{Cl2}$ begins to interact with the indene an initial ion pair is formed.  In the case of chlorine, it is not always clear whether

- a cyclic halonium ion (the 3-membered structure on the bottom left)
- an open ion (the structure on the bottom right)
- or an equilibrium between the two ions occurs

[Side Note: In electrophilic bromination reactions involving alkenes, bromonium ions are very common intermediates usually leading to *trans* addition.  However, chlorine isn't as polarizable as bromine and in this particular case with indene, the open ion is extremely stable due to its benzylic nature. Hence the involvement of only a chloronium ion is questionable in this case.]

[image]

**Analysis**

As mentioned above, **ions are not very well stabilized in the non-polar solvent**. As a result

- the two ions (one positive, one negative) will tend to stay **close together  (tight ion pair**) and stabilize each other
- and further due to this lack of stabilization they will have a **short lifetime** leading to **quick collapse** to products.

Both of these factors (chlorines located close to one another, short lifetime doesn't allow much movement of the second chlorine) favor *syn* collapse - addition of the second chlorine from the same side that the first chlorine is on.

If we were to repeat the reaction in a polar solvent that would allow the ions to separate and have a longer lifetime, more *trans* product from *anti* addition would be expected.